# Problems with decimal formatting axes

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, axis

I have a data set with two variables, each ranging in values of 0 to 100 with many decimal places. When I create a scatter plot in R using ggplot2, this is what it looks like (see image). I just want 0, 50, 100 on both axes, with 0,0 where the axes intersect. I'm new to R but I can't figure out why it's plotting it this way or how to fix it!

This is the code that gives the result I'm attaching in the image:

```
ggplot(MergedDataSets, aes(x = VMMI_2016_IMPORTED, y = XRCOV_AC_IMPORTED)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "vmmi", y = "invasive cover") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  scale_y_discrete(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))
```

[image]

I've tried a bunch of methods for changing the intervals (with scale_x_discrete and scale_x_continuous but that gave errors), rounding the decimals (thinking maybe that was the issue, using label_number but that gave errors too), reversing the x-axis using the reverse function. Here's a smattering of my attempts:

```r
ggplot(MergedDataSets, aes(x = VMMI_2016_IMPORTED, y = XRCOV_AC_IMPORTED)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "vmmi", y = "invasive cover") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_number(accuracy = 1))
# Error in `train_continuous()`:
# ! Discrete value supplied to a continuous scale

ggplot(MergedDataSets, aes(x = VMMI_2016_IMPORTED, y = XRCOV_AC_IMPORTED)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "vmmi", y = "invasive cover") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), number_format(accuracy = 0.01)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), number_format(accuracy = 0.01))
# Error in number_format(accuracy = 0.01) : 
#   could not find function "number_format"

ggplot(MergedDataSets, aes(x = VMMI_2016_IMPORTED, y = XRCOV_AC_IMPORTED)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "vmmi", y = "invasive cover") +   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), labels = label_number(accuracy = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), labels = label_number(accuracy = 1))
# Error in label_number(accuracy = 1) : 
#   could not find function "label_number"

ggplot(MergedDataSets, aes(x = VMMI_2016_IMPORTED, y = XRCOV_AC_IMPORTED)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "vmmi", y = "invasive cover") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), format(x, nsmall = 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 10), format(x, nsmall = 2))
# Error: object 'x' not found
```

**EDIT** Feb 3: here is the output from dput as requested, for the two variables I'm trying to plot:

XRCOV_AC_IMPORTED = c("1.99",
"13.78", "0", "0", "0", "0.01"), VMMI_2016_IMPORTED = c("61.285514229999997",
"50.856517340000003", "66.884888160000003", "73.28915404",
"54.280754020000003", "53.066818599999998")

I also tried the other two suggestions to no avail. Here is the code I used and the error message it returned:

```
library(scales)
ggplot(MergedDataSets, aes(x = VMMI_2016_IMPORTED, y = XRCOV_AC_IMPORTED)) + geom_point() + labs(x = "vmmi", y = "invasive cover") +   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) + scale_y_continuous (breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10))
```

Error in `train_continuous()`:
! Discrete value supplied to a continuous scale
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Try your original code with `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)` (note use continuous not discrete).

Comment: Have you tired loading `library(scales)` first.  That should clear up many of the errors

Comment: The error `Discrete value supplied to a continuous scale` suggests to me that your variables are discrete not continuous, so numeric breaks are not going to work like you expect. Please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(MergedDataSets))` to a new [code block] so we can see what we're dealing with.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Sarah. Were the above comments helpful? It will be much easier to  answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)